# Jquery ui droppable exclude the particular division

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

Ex:

```
<div class="droppable">
     <div class="except_this_div"></div>
</div >
```

I have a jquery ui droppable event for the above example in which the drop should not happen for

`$('.droppable').droppable({});`

I need to exclude the droppable only for `<div class="except_this_div"></div>`

Comment: related bug report https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14933#ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the jquery ui draggable revert function.

HTML

```
<div class="droppable">
  <div class="except_this_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="draggable">
```

JQuery

```
var revert;

$('.droppable').droppable({  
            drop: function( event, ui ){
            revert = false;
        }
});

$('.except_this_div').droppable({
  greedy: true
});

$('.draggable').draggable({
  revert: function(){
    return revert;
  },
  start: function(){
    revert = true;  
  }
});
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qL0tb12h/2/

Comment: @Niyaz please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, or leave feedback. Thanks

Comment: Thanks trever for your kind help